# Australian permanent resident countries to visit without visa

Tags: visas, australia, australian-residents

I have some friends who are PR of Australia and I wonder what countries allows Australian permanent residents to visit without a visa? I know that New Zealand doesn't require a visa for Australian permanent residents, but are there any other countries?
Also does being an Australian Permanent resident give any advantages when applying for any visa? Like what are the travelling benefits an Australian Permanent resident has?

Comment: In most cases the UK (along with the rest of the affluent Commonwealth) would consider it as a boost to the applicant's credibility.  So would Schengen.   But do you need an answer for all 290+ countries?

Comment: @GayotFow no, I'm talking about US, canada and Europe.

Comment: Turkey would also grant you an immediate e-visa if you have an Australian PR but would normally require a full visa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most visitor visa regimes are based solely on citizenship, with permanent resident status having no effect.  There are some exceptions, however, where countries that have unusually close relationships will waive visa requirements for one another's permanent residents.  The exceptions I know of concern certain cases in the EU, and US permanent residents, who do not need visas for short visits to Canada.  I was unaware of a similar arrangement between Australia and New Zealand, but I am not surprised to learn about it.

I don't know of any other countries that exempt Australian permanent residents from a visitor visa requirement.

Transit visas are another matter.  Many countries will waive transit visa requirements for those with permanent resident status in certain "developed" countries, such as Australia.  The UK comes to mind, as does South Korea (thanks to [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal) for pointing that out).

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  Australian PR does smooth the way in some random countries, eg. you can do visa-free transit in South Korea: http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?catSeq=401&categoryId=2&parentId=385&showMenuId=375

Comment: @jpatokal great, I'll add South Korea to the transit list.  The OP is asking about visit, though, not transit, so the transit angle is more of a digression than anything else.

Comment: The "transit" in question allows stays of up to 30 days in Korea.

Comment: Another exception is the GCC. A permanent resident of the GCC is entitled to visa-on-arrival entry to other member states of the GCC (except Saudi Arabia); even if they needed a visa due to their nationality.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid is the GCC relevant to Australian permanent residents?

Comment: @phoog I was referring to this: _"Most visitor visa regimes are based solely on citizenship, with permanent resident status having no effect. There are some exceptions, however, where countries that have unusually close relationships will waive visa requirements for one another's permanent residents."_

Comment: @BurhanKhalud a permanent resident of GCC **and from a selected list of professions**.. i.e. someone in GCC with Carpenter trade in his work visa cannnot visit Oman. And do they call it PR, because it is not permanent, it needs to be renewed, and always has an expiry date.

Comment: Its permanent in that you have rights to multiple entry and work - and just like in other places (like the US "Green Card") a permanent resident status is subject to renewal - because the premise under which it is granted (for example, as the basis of working there) is decidedly _not_ permanent and also subject to renewal. If you keep renewing it, you could stay indefinitely - you just don't have the same rights as a citizen.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid US green card renewal is about the document only.  The expiration of the document does not imply the expiration of the status.

Answer (score 2):

Singapore and Philippines waive visa (Tourist/Visit) requirements for Aussie PRs regardless of their passport.

Visa is available in Singapore only for Air Travel (Entering from Malaysia by road doesn't entitle a visa-free entry)

For Philippines, visa free entry is available only at Manila airport.

https://www.ica.gov.sg/enteranddeparting/before/enteranddeparting_before_vftf
https://philippines.visahq.com.au/requirements/india/resident-australia/

Answer (score 2):

Australian PRs also get a visa-on-arrival to Georgia at Tbilisi airport.

The most current version of this information is on the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Georgia website](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=206&lang=Eng)

Comment: Welcome Random Aussie Bloke, could you please edit your answer and add the relevant parts of the link you mentioned? So that your answer becomes more complete, without needing to check an external source?

Comment: Hey mate gmauch 

--- the relevant part is already in there: it is that Aussie PRs get a visa-on-arrival.

I'd have thought that citing the source of info is what would add credibility to a post or message. The link in there is form the Georgian Government's website. It can't be that hard to click on it and get the info from the source.

On a practical basis, if that policy ever changes the link to the Georgian Government's page is what would help a reader/participant in this conversation.

Comment: Hello Random Aussie Bloke, when I reviewed your answer I didn't check the link, but we encourage answers to be as complete as possible, so that if a link ever becomes outdated, we still have the complete answer without external dependencies. That said IMHO, your question has enough information to be useful, I just edited it. You can check it, or revert if you don't feel it is better worded/formatted now.

Comment: Looks like you're some kind of administrator. Why didn't you say so? It would have added context to your suggestion. I've made a minor text change, but otherwise your edit's great. Your addition is valid, and is well formatted. Thanks.

Comment: @RandomAussieBloke, all long time users on Stack Exchange will do some moderation tasks like asking for more information and editing questions and answers. New users can but will be monitored.

Comment: Good to know, Welleke. This is good practice and adds credibility to posts on this site. It would be nice to tell people when a moderation task is being carried out because it adds some gravitas to the suggestion or edit. Else it just looks like someone voicing an opinion and pressuring you to take it on board -- Cheers.